# Django delete in a transaction

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

In a Django view, if two requests enter an atomic block that `get`s a model instance (that exists at the time they both enter the block) and `delete`s it

```
with transaction.atomic():
  MyModel.objects.get(
    id=1234
  ).delete()
```

what happens when they exit the block? Would an exception be raised on one of them? If so, what exception? (i.e. so I can catch it)

Comment: You could use [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to lock the row so that another request cannot read it in-between the get and the delete

Comment: The second request would raise `MyModel.DoesNotExist` when the lock was freed as the row would no longer be there

Comment: @IainShelvington That is helpful... but in the current form without `select_for_update`, would no exception be raised?

Comment: `delete` would not raise an exception, it just returns the number of deleted rows. It would probably just return `0`

Comment: @IainShelvington Ah that's interesting... if `delete` returns `0`, does that mean that `atomic` is a bit misnamed? It's not really atomic... a client's view of the database can change depending on what other database clients do during the lifetime of the transaction?